# Datastage String Conversion to Timestamp

Tags: datastage

I have been tasked with converting a string which can come in different formats like such(mm/dd/yyyy, m/dd/yyyy, or mm/d/yyyy). However, it needs to be converted into a Timestamp with the following format (yyyy-mm-dd-00.00.000000). I have tried multiple conversion techniques within the Transformer stage; however, I have been unsuccessful. Basically, I pull the data from a file and stage it into a file in the same format as the table. I then insert into the database using the second file.

Comment: So what have you tried? Do you use Enterprise Edition or Server?

Comment: Which IIS version are you using?
 1. Have you ever try to validate the format into a conditionals into the Transformer Stage?
 2. Have you ever used Iconv and Oconv functions? You can validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I was running into was the fact that the format could be mm/dd/yyyy or m/d/yyyy. The solution to this was to add a ",s" to my StringToTimestamp function.

StringtoTimestamp(Input,,"%(m,s)/%(d,s)/%yyyy %hh:%nn:%ss").